# c# listview backcolor is not on all row in the begining

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem, backcolor

I have listview, and I initial it with BackColor to the first item :

```
 listView1.Items[0].BackColor = Color.LightBlue;
```

the problem is that in the beginning, the back color is only behind the item itself, for example:
the first item is "first" and BackColor will be behind the word "first".

now, if I press anyware the BackColor is ok and will be behind all row.

why is that ?

Comment: Can you show us your listview code

Comment: there is no code.
the problem is that when i select item, i want it will choose all line, not only the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that "FullRowSelect" property was "false"
needs to be "true"